# LINQ Join 2 List<T>s

Tags: c#, linq

Preface: I don't understand what this does:

```
o => o.ID, i => i.ID, (o, id) => o
```

So go easy on me.   :-)

---

I have 2 lists that I need to join together:

```
// list1 contains ALL contacts for a customer.
// Each item has a unique ID.
// There are no duplicates.
ContactCollection list1 = myCustomer.GetContacts();

// list2 contains the customer contacts (in list1) relevant to a REPORT
// the items in this list may have properties that differ from those in list1.
/*****/// e.g.:
/*****/        bool SelectedForNotification; 
/*****///  may be different.
ContactCollection list2 = myReport.GetContacts();
```

I need to create a third ContactCollection that contains all of the contacts in `list1` but with the properties of the items in `list2`, if the item is in the list[2] (`list3.Count == list1.Count`).

---

**I need to replace all items in `list1` with the items in `list2` where items in `list1` have the IDs of the items in `list2`. The resulting list (`list3`) should contain the same number of items at `list1`.**

I feel as though I'm not making any sense. So, please ask questions in the comments and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Lets use a concrete example. Lets say List 1 contains 3 elements, and List 2 contains 2 elements. Each of the 'Contacts' has some set of properties. You want it such that you can make a List 3, that has every item from List1 in List3, with each element of List3 having set the properties that were set in List2?

Comment: I don't think you can use Linq to just create the List3 - Say an element from List1 did not set the 'Property24' property, but all the elements from List2 do. In addition, if an element only exists in List1, where does the data come from that will populate the 'Property24' property on the item that is exclusive to List1?

There is missing data there.

Comment: It would be fine to leave `Property24` unset; although I don't think this will be a problem.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Joins are not so difficult, but your problem could probably use some further explanation.

To join two lists, you could do something like

```
var joined = from Item1 in list1
             join Item2 in list2
             on Item1.Id equals Item2.Id // join on some property
             select new { Item1, Item2 };
```

this will give an `IEnumerable<'a>`, where 'a is an anonymous type holding an item from list1 and its related item from list2. You could then choose which objects' properties to use as needed.

To get the result to a concrete list, all that is needed is a call to .ToList(). You can do that like

```
var list3 = joined.ToList();
// or
var list3 = (from Item1 in list1
             join Item2 in list2
             on Item1.Id equals Item2.Id // join on some property
             select new { Item1, Item2 }).ToList();
```

To do a left join to select all elements from list1 even without a match in list2, you can do something like this

```
var list3 = (from Item1 in list1
             join Item2 in list2
             on Item1.Id equals Item2.Id // join on some property
             into grouping
             from Item2 in grouping.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new { Item1, Item2 }).ToList();
```

This will give you a list where Item1 equals the item from the first list and Item2 will either equal the matching item from the second list *or* the default, which will be null for a reference type.

Comment: `List3.Count()` should equal `List1.Count()`. How would I go about `select`ing ALL items in `list1`, replacing `Item1` with `Item2` when `Item1.Id == Item2.Id`?

Comment: well well, that is almost exactly what I came up with  (I just posted it as an answer)! I'll test yours in a second and get back to ya.

Comment: @David, yours is good. It will give you the second item unless it does not exist, when it will give you the first item. My solution gives you *both* items and allows you to pick and choose properties later. If your needs are met by just having the single item, then you are good to go.

Answer (score 13):

Here is what I came up with (based on [this](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/OuterJoinSample.ashx)):

```
List<Contact> list3 = (from item1 in list1
    join item2 in list2
    on item1.ContactID equals item2.ContactID into g
    from o in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select o == null ? item1 :o).ToList<Contact>();
```

My favorite part is the big nosed smiley

### `:o)`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a [DotNetFiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/UySDms) with a Linq Group Join

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Order 
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public Order(int id, string name)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }   
}
class OrderItem
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public int OrderId;
    public OrderItem(int id, string name, int orderId)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.OrderId = orderId;
    }
}
List<Order> orders = new List<Order>() 
{
    new Order(1, "one"), 
    new Order(2, "two") 
};
List<OrderItem> orderItems = new List<OrderItem>()
{
    new OrderItem(1, "itemOne", 1),
    new OrderItem(2, "itemTwo", 1), 
    new OrderItem(3, "itemThree", 1), 
    new OrderItem(4, "itemFour", 2), 
    new OrderItem(5, "itemFive", 2)
};
var joined = 
    from o in orders
    join oi in orderItems
    on o.Id equals oi.OrderId into gj // gj means group join and is a collection OrderItem
    select new { o, gj };

// this is just to write the results to the console
string columns = "{0,-20} {1, -20}";
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(columns, "Order", "Item Count"));
foreach(var j in joined)
{
    Console.WriteLine(columns, j.o.Name, j.gj.Count() );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you don't really need a full-join.  You could instead do a semi-join, checking each contact in list 2 to see if it is contained in list 1:

`ContactCollection list3 = list2.Where(c => list1.Contains(c));`

I don't know how big your lists are, but note that this approach has O(n*m) complexity unless list1 is sorted or supports fast lookups (as in a hashset), in which case it could be as efficient as O(n*log(m)) or rewritten as a merge-join and be O(n).

Comment: there will be at most 10-20 in a list.

Comment: Then this will probably be faster than a naive LINQ join since the LINQ implementation builds a hash-based lookup anyways, and for such few elements the overhead probably is greater.

Comment: `list3.Count()' should equal `list1.Count()`