# How to merge two lists on a given property

Tags: c#, linq

I have two queries, each one returning a list of objects.

```
List<A> list1 = (....query...)
List<A> list2 = (....query...)
```

"A" is an object model.

Both queries return almost the same objects but with different properties set.

I want to remove duplicates merge them into a single list based on a property of object A.

Basically something like this:

```
List<A> finalLis = list1 join list2 on elemList1.somePropID == elemList2.somePropID
```

In simple C# style it would be something like this:

```
foreach(elem1 : list1) {
    foreach(elem2: list1) {
       if(elem1.someID == elem2.someID) {
           elem1.someProp = elem2.someProp
           elem1.otherProp = elem2.otherProp
        }
     }
}
```

I don't want to do it in this way because I'm sure there's a more elegant way in linq.

If you have any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: Do you want to have items from the second collection, that does not match any item ID in the first collection, in the result set?

Comment: no....the elements in the first list are almost the same elements as those in the second list. The ideea is that in the first list some properties are not set, but those values can be found in their counterparts. The final list is the first list but with all the properties set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq can help you with selecting but not with updating. So you won't get rid of `foreach` statement. So your task could be written with linq like this:

```
//the query is like LEFT JOIN in SQL
var query = from x in list1
            join y in list2 on x.IDItem equals y.IDItem
            into z
            from q in z.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new {IOne = x, ITwo = q};
foreach (var pair in query)
{
    if (pair.ITwo != null) // && pair.IOne.OneProperty != null
        pair.IOne.OneProperty = pair.ITwo.TwoProperty;
}

var resultList = query.Select(x => x.IOne).ToList();
```

You can check the results [here](http://ideone.com/ecXeXg).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<A> list = (from e1 in list1
           join e2 in list2
           on e1.ID equals e2.ID
           select new A
           {
              ID = l2.ID,
              someProp1 = l2.someProp1,
              someProp2 = l2.someProp2
           }).ToList();
```

Then you would have a third list with all the elements.

This link might help: [LINQ Join 2 List<T>s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723985/linq-join-2-listts)

Comment: It will not include unique objects from each list (with unique ID). Also it will create new objects instead of updating existing.

Comment: But he said that the differences are some properties not set to list1 and set to list2. And the way the code sample was written I tought he wanted a third list.

Answer (score 0):

Linq is for *querying*, not *updating*.  You can simplify the join but you'll still need to loop to do the update.

Something like:

```
List<A> finalList = 
   from item1 in list1 
   join item2 in list2 on item1.somePropID equals item2.somePropID 
   select new{Item1 = item1, Item2 = item2};

foreach(var item in finalList)
{
    item.Item2.someProp1 = item.Item1.someProp1;
    item.Item2.someProp2 = item.Item1.someProp2;
}
```

Comment: Same thing - not joined IDs are missing in final list.

Comment: OK I did not see the comment that explained that.

Answer (score 0):

It is right to want to use LINQ.

The answers here are all equivalent to the given C# snippet apart from that the snippet is very inefficient and will cause list1.Length * list2.Length operations.

Using LINQ joins is much more efficient and results in roughly list1.Length + list2.Length operations.

This is because the join on the id will do something like this using a dictionary

```
// create a dict so that you can lookup things in item1 based on id
var list1IdToADict = list1.ToDictionary(a => a.id);

//filter out things not in both lists (join on there id)
var joinedList2 = list2.Where(a => list1IdToADict.ContainsKey(a.id));
```

Other answers are more elagant but if you wanted to do it this way you could finish with

```
foreach(var a in joinedList2){
    a.someProp = list1IdToADict[a.id].someProp;
    a.otherProp = list1IdToADict[a.id].otherProp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any solution over `List<T>` will perform at N * Log(n) at best because the lists need to be sorted.

Implement equality members on your model and use a `HashSet<T>` instead.

This is optimal both in complexity and in allocations.

```
var set1 = new HashSet<Model>
{
    new Model(0, "000"),
    new Model(2, "222"),
    new Model(4, "444"),
};

var set2 = new HashSet<Model>
{
    new Model(1, "111"),
    new Model(2, "2222"),
    new Model(3, "333"),
};

set1.ExceptWith(set2);
set1.UnionWith(set2);
```

To add, it will  be faster to use the overwriting set as the result set.

```
set2.UnionWith(set1);
```

Class `Model` in the above sample:

```
class Model
{
    public readonly int Id;
    public string Data;

    public Model(int id, string data)
    {
        Id = id;
        Data = data;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id;
    }

    protected bool Equals(Model other)
    {
        return Id == other.Id;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        return obj.GetType() == GetType() && Equals((Model) obj);
    }
}
```