# LINQ: join between results of two separate contexts

Tags: c#, linq

I know LINQ doesn't support two diff contexts in a standard 'join'.

Having said that, what I'm trying to do is, pull together a list of, shall we say, 'employees', from a 'user' and 'contact' contexts. 
(These are edmx's that are from an old project, that I'm not about to mess with.)

Thing is, 'users' is WHO I want to get, but their demographics reside inside the 'contacts'. Here's the two current LINQ's:

```
        var users = _pets_dc.Users
            .Select(p => p)
            .Where(x => x.Active)
            .ToList();

        var contacts = _poems_dc.Contacts
            .Select(p => p)
            .Where(x => x.Active)
            .ToList();
```

I need **contacts** where 'user.Contact_GUID' equals 'contacts.Contact_GUID'.

I have tried:

```
var query = contacts
    .Where(x => x.Contact_GUID == users
        .Select(y => y.Contact_GUID)
        .FirstOrDefault());
```

to no avail... this only brings back one contact, but won't work without `.FirstOrDefault()`. Any ideas?

Comment: Users are pets? This takes "lusers" to a whole new level...

Comment: I have no idea, this was how it was when I got here.. I'm guessing the ambiguity was for security

Comment: I'm just kidding. I just find your variable names humorous.

Comment: If you unlink your data from your context (`ToList` plus some other manipulation) you should be able to perform any linq operation you want in yourself. Downside is you need to pull more data from your contexts.

Comment: In your solution, can youy try the following code:
 users.Select(y => y.Contact_GUID).Contains(x.Contact_GUID)

This will give only match the contact_GUID, which are there in either collection. In current version you are comparing a Guid to List<GUID>, so it will not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Contact_GUID in both tables if you have FK in users table try using first query with `include`

```
var users = _pets_dc.Users.Include("Contacts")
            .Where(x => x.Active)
            .ToList();
```

you can try the following anyway:

```
var joined = from list1 in users 
                 join list2 in contacts
                 on list1.Contact_GUID equals list2.Contact_GUID 
                 select new { list1, list2 };
```

ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2724018/1166597

Comment: a variable object for each table, you can access properites using: `users.list1.Contact_GUID`, you can user any variable name than list1,list2

Comment: What is this `equals` operator? In C#, it's `==`.

Comment: @Jashaszun, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509017.aspx#JoinUsingEntityFields

Comment: This is what worked, thanks OldTrain 
var users = _pets_dc.Users
                .Select(p => p)
                .Where(x => x.Active)
                .ToList();

            var contacts = _poems_dc.Contacts
                .Select(p => p)
                .Where(x => x.Active)
                .ToList();

            var query = from Users in users
                         join Contacts in contacts
                         on Users.Contact_GUID equals Contacts.Contact_GUID
                         select new { Contacts };

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code:

```
  var result = users.Select(e => contacts.Where(x => x.Contact_GUID == e.Contact_GUID));
```

Comment: kinda worked, sort of... not your fault though. What I need is in the 'Contacts'. so a lil mod to it might work but the above answer is working correct for me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Joining is one of the option that would work here, but you can modify your current solution as follows:

```
var query = contacts
    .Where(x => users
               .Select(y => y.Contact_GUID).Contains(x.Contact_GUID)
           ).FirstOrDefault());
```

`Contains` will check the `Guid` in a given list, in original solution you are comparing Guid with `List<Guid>`, which would fail

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

```
var query = from person in users
                    join contact in contacts on person.Contact_GUID equals contact.GUID into employees
                    from employee in employees.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new Employee() { User = person, Demographic = employee.Demographic };
```

var employees = query.ToList();

Option 2:

```
var query = from person in users
                    join contact in contacts on person.Contact_GUID equals contact.GUID into employees
                    from employee in employees.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new { person.FirstName, person.LastName, employee.Demographic };
```

var employees = query.ToList();