# Filter items from database based on a List<>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method that accepts two `List<int>` for which I need to get data from the database based on the `List<>`s.

So, I receive a `List<PersonId>` and  `List<NationalityId>` for example, and I need to get a result set where records match the `PersonIds` and `NationalistId`s.

```
public List<PersonDTO> SearchPeople(List<int> persons, Lisy<int> nationalities)
{
  var results = (from c in myDbContect.People where .... select c).ToList();
}
```

Note that I think Lists might be null.

Is there an efficient way?
I was going to try:

```
where ((persons != null && persons.Count > 0) && persons persons.Contains(x=>x.PersonId))
```

But this would generate rather inefficient SQL, and as I add more search parameters, the linq may get very messy.

Is there an efficient way to achieve this?

The join method may be easy to read, but the issue I face is that IF the input list is empty, then it shouldn't filter. That is, if nationalities is empty, don't filter any out:

```
    var results = (from c in entities.Persons
                   join p in persons on c.PersonId equals b
                   join n in nationalities on c.NationalityId equals n
```

equals n
                       select c).ToList();

This would return no results if any of the lists were empty. Which, is bad.

Comment: "But this would generate rather inefficient SQL" - how do you know that? Filtering is best done in the database.....

Comment: Sounds like you want to join... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723985/linq-join-2-listts

Comment: @MitchWheat, while what you are saying is true, in this particular case if lists contain more than about 2000 items combined the resulting query won't be able to execute at all - all the values in the list are translated to a parameter each and a sql query has a limit on number of parameters.

Comment: Maximum number of parameters in the sql query is 2100.Passing in a CSV list of values in a single parameter (and using a table value split function to turn those into rows), or using a table value parameter would be much easier than handling all of those input parameters.

Comment: Joining to the List<int> seems like a valid, assuming a join generates an INNER join? If so, how can I do this, with the knowledge that if the list is empty, or null, then all values must be returned?

Comment: I've edited the question, as the join method seems cleanest, but ... if the input list is empty, it should not filter everything, but rather be ignored.

Comment: @Craig Why are you `INNER JOIN`ing? Are you selecting from the `List<int>`? Use a `WHERE id IN`/`Where(Predicate)`, it shows much better intent (unless you are using MySQL in which case...use a real RDBMS).

Answer (score 1):

If you join an `IQueryable` with an `IEnumerable` (in this case, `entities.Persons` and `persons`), your filtering will not happen within your query.  Instead, your `IQueryable` is enumerated, retrieving all of your records from the database, while the join is performed in memory using the `IEnumerable` join method.

To perform your filtering against a list within your query, there are two main options:

1. Join using an `IQueryable` on both sides.  This might be possible if your list of ids comes from the execution of another query, in which case you can use the underlying query in your join instead of the resulting set of ids.
2. Use the contains operator against your list.  This is only possible with small lists, because each additional id requires its own query parameter.  If you have many ids, you can possibly extend this approach with batching.

If you want to skip filtering when the list is empty, then you might consider using the extension method invocation instead of the LINQ syntax.  This allows you to use an `if` statement:

```
IQueryable<Person> persons = entities.persons;
List<int> personIds = new List<int>();
if(personIds.Count > 0)
{
    persons = persons.Where(p => personIds.Contains(p.PersonId));
}
var results = persons.ToList();
```

Note that the `Where` predicate uses option #2 above, and is only applied if there are any ids in the collection.

Comment: So, in your example above, the first line will NOT query the database. Then, I can have two 'if' statements for the two lists that I need to check. i.e. add two where clauses, and Linq will 'merge' them somehow? And then the query is only executed in the .ToList() at the end?

Comment: @Craig Yes, that is correct.  Your LINQ query with the `from` / `join` syntax is just syntactic sugar that the compiler translates as calls to `Queryable` or `Enumerable` static methods (depending on the type).  Execution of LINQ statements is always deferred until enumerated (e.g. using `ToList`). In the case of `Enumerable`, each call builds up a pipeline to process items in a streaming fashion.  In the case of `Queryable`, each call builds onto an expression tree that is translated to a data store operation (e.g. SQL query).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the records for persons for example if the list is empty and then filter by nationalityId list if its not empty you can do something like this:

```
List<int> personsIds = ...;
List<int> nationalitiesIds = ...;

var results = (from c in entities.Persons
                   join p in persons on c.PersonId equals b
                   join n in nationalities on c.NationalityId equals n
                   where ((personsIds == null || personsIds.Contains(p.Id)) 
                       && (nationalitiesIds == null || nationalitiesIds.Contains(n.Id))
select c).ToList();
```