# Match values in two different lists using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, list

Apologies if this has been asked before, I couldn't find an answer to my question.

I have two lists, lets say:

```
List<Job> jobs;
List<Period> periods;
```

The classes Job and Period contain an identifier, JobID, which is used to link them together. In the two lists there is a 1:1 relationship between these objects, i.e. for each Job there is 1 Period.

What is the most efficient way using Linq to pair each Job with its corresponding period? I am currently doing this:

```
Period matchingPeriod;
for (int i = 0; i < jobs.Count; i++)
{
    matchingPeriod = periods.Single(j => j.JobID== jobs[i].JobID);
    //other code 
}
```

But in  large datasets this takes ages.
Many thanks.

Comment: I think you can use Linq.Join http://www.dotnetperls.com/join

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723985/linq-join-2-listts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var result = jobs.Join(
    periods,
    job => job.JobID,
    period => period.JobID,
    (job, period) => new { Job = job, Period = period }
);
```

or

```
var result = 
    from j in Jobs
    join p in Periods on j.JobID equals p.JobID
    select new { Job = j, Period = p };
```

Comment: When it comes to `Join` i prefer query synta. Due to LINQ's deferred execution you can also separate it in multiple queries(`Join` in query and rest in method syntax) without any performance impacts.

Comment: @TimSchmelter same here. Just thought I'd show the OP what choice he has.

Answer (score 0):

```
var periods = (from j in jobs
               join p in periods on j.Id  equals p.JobID
               select p).ToList();
```

Comment: The OP claims to always have a 1:1 relationship between jobs and periods. He needs to put them into correspondence.