# Join two lists of objects: All properties from one list, only certain properties from the other one

Tags: c#, linq, xmlserializer

I have two classes:

```
class Class1
{
    public int ProductId  { get; set; }
    public string ProductName  { get; set; }
    public int Amount  { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}

class Class2
{
    public id ProductId  { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateTime { get; set; }
    public int ItemState  { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

I create two lists for each of this class:

```
public List<Class1> listClass1 { get; set; } = new List<Class1>();
public List<Class2> listClass2 { get; set; } = new List<Class2>();
```

Now I want to create a new list by joining both lists on the `ProductID` containing all properties from `Class1` and just `UpdateTime` and `ItemState` from `Class2`. What is the best way to do this?

(The ultimate goal is to let the user save the current session to let him continue with his work later, for this I need the complete `listClass1` and the mentioned properties of `listClass2`. The idea is to use an `XmlSerializer` on the merged list and save it into an XML file. To open the file, I want to deserialize it. If you have a better approach to let the user save his session, I'm all ears.)

Comment: For the "best way to do" is `LINQ` as you tagged already! Or please post some code where you are failing to achieve the result. That will help.

Comment: And what did you try? Basically you´re on the right way: just search for "join two tables with linq".

Comment: Thanks guys. And, point taken, next time I'll put more effort in trying to solve it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to make a third class which represents the joined parameter set.

```
public class Class1_2
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdateTime { get; set; }
    public int ItemState { get; set; }
}
```

How to join 2 Lists is described in [LINQ Join 2 Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723985/linq-join-2-listts). So you would end up with something like this:

```
List<Class1_2> joinedList = (from item1 in listClass1
                             join item2 in listClass2
                             on item1.ProductId equals item2.ProductId
                             select new Class1_2
                             {
                                 ProductId = item1.ProductId,
                                 Amount = item1.Amount,
                                 ProductName = item1.ProductName,
                                 Category = item1.Category,
                                 ItemState = item2.ItemState,
                                 UpdateTime = item2.UpdateTime
                             }).ToList();
```

Explanation: You join the items on the particular property. If it is equal in both lists you take the item and construct a new one with the **selected** properties. The join would also work without `Class1_2` but then you get a result of `dynamic` type. The advantage of the new `Class_1_2` is that you can use it for serialization with a defined structure.

**EDIT**

you could also use a second constructor in `Class1_2`

```
public Class1_2(Class1 c1, Class2 c2)
{
    ProductId = c1.ProductId;
    Amount = c1.Amount;
    ProductName = c1.ProductName;
    Category = c1.Category;
    ItemState = c2.ItemState;
    UpdateTime = c2.UpdateTime;
}
```

that would simplify a little the `select` statement to:

```
select new Class1_2(item1, item2)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!